# Можно ли менять позиции блоков, когда создаешь медиа запросы?

Tags: css, html5

[image]

Чтобы блоки с текстом встали по горизонтали, а карта ушла пол них, когда уменьшаешь ширину сайта

Comment: Да. Можно. В чем проблема?

Comment: Не знаю, как это делается. Можете предложить вариант?

Comment: display flex а в медиа запросе flex-wrap wrap и все дела